# How to fix the height of a <div> element?

Tags: css, html

I've defined my div's height in a stylesheet:

```
.topbar{
  width:100%;
  height:70px;
  background-color:#475;
}
```

But as soon as text is entered into the div, the divs height changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: welcome at stackoverflow. It helps a lot to  give us a live example at jsbin.com to understand better the problem and your requirement

Answer (score 61, accepted):

change the div to display block

```
.topbar{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#475;
    overflow:scroll;
    }
```

i made a jsfiddle example here please check

http://jsfiddle.net/TgPRM/

Comment: @jake , change the overflow to scroll also, it gives you verticaland horizontal bars http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: @jake give a background and see background-color:#00FF00; , it won't increase the height but just the text goes over it, it may look like that height increase...s

Answer (score 22):

If you want to keep the height of the DIV absolute, regardless of the amount of text inside use the following:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use min-height and max-height. It was very useful for me

Answer (score 1):

I think height and overflow should work, like height 70px or according to need. And overflow could be auto like this:

```
.topbar{
  width:100%;
  height:70px;
  background-color:#475;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Note: overflow with scroll will show the area of scrollbar either its visible or not I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can try max-height: 70px; See if that works.